# XSLT Fit External Graphic into a block

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to fit my SVG image into a block in XSLT.
With a PNG image it works fine but when I use an svg image the scaling doesn`t work.

this is my code:

```
<fo:block>

    <fo:external-graphic content-height="20mm" content-width="60mm" 
    scaling="non-uniform" src="{@src}">

    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of  select="/ush:document/u:test/@src" />
    </xsl:attribute>

    </fo:external-graphic>

</fo:block>
```

This is the an example of how it looks now:

[image: Example]

can someone help me?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you able to add a screenshot and describe what went wrong?

Comment: scaling="non-uniform" is horrible, as it will throw away the relationship between height and width of the image. Never use that unless you really want a distorted image.

Comment: @TonyGraham The image doesn`t fit the box it displays also outside of the box

Comment: What is part of the image? Just the rail profile, or the horizontal lines to the left of it as well?

Comment: @hobbes the horizontal lines to the left and right and on the top is doesn`t scale down

Comment: At first glance, those lines look to be about 60 mm wide. If you want them smaller, you have to change the width attribute.

Comment: hello @Hobbes but when i change the SVG image the other image again does something whole different I want all SVG to react some and fit itself into the block

Comment: Are you trying to place 2 images into 1 fo:external-graphic?

Comment: @Hobbes no just 1 I am just trying to fit every SVG image in the block but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Which version of which formatter are you using?

Comment: @Hobbes version 1.0

Comment: As @Hobbes says, `scaling="non-uniform"` is probably not what you want.  I don't see it being the cause of your problem, but it will distort your image unless the image has exactly the same aspect ratio as the width and height that you specify.

Comment: Is there only one SVG image that is a problem or all SVG images?

Comment: All the SVG image act different some get very small some to large but when I use PNG the code i provided works fine

Comment: Can you add a clearer image? I can't tell what is part of the image and which lines are the cell boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what to do when the image-width is different from the width of the fo:external-graphic:

```
<fo:external-graphic width="60mm" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/>
```

width specifies the width of the viewport, content-width specifies the width of the image in the viewport.

Comment: Hello @hobbes look at my question i have added an image this is what happens when I add the witdth and scale down to fit.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the image is in a table cell.  Presumably you want to scale the image to fit the table cell:

```
<fo:external-graphic width="100%" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" src="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic src="/path/right.png"/>
                                  </fo:block>
                                  </fo:table-cell>
```